# How to open file using Intents programatically?

Tags: java, android

I have following code for opening files programatically:

```
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, type);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

But now I need to set MIME-type of file, and it isn't universal method for all files. Is there any mean for opening file through Intent without defining type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just use `intent.setData()`, instead of `intent.setDataAndType()`. Although, the result may not be as desirable as when the type is defined.

You can also use a convenience `Intent` constructor, and remove the "setData" call, like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, path);
```